# Can't see connexion to Postgresql using php

Tags: postgresql, php, connections

I have created a php form to connect to a remote postgresql database. It seems that I can log in successfully because my message "connexion succeeded" appears.
But I can't see the corresponding line in the pg_stat_activity view.
Does it mean that the connexion is closed just after completion ? or is there some other reason ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using pg_pconnect creates a permanent connection not like pg_connect I was using.